# Gradle Download And Unzip Multiple Dependencies

Tags: android-studio, gradle, groovy, dependencies, artifactory

I have a generic Artifatory repo that contains some zip files that I need to download and extract in an Android Studio project. I am new to Gradle but found that using an Ivy repository object maybe the best way to do this instead of just downloading the files using a Gradle task which calls curl.

I have managed to get a single zip file downloaded and extracted but soon as I try to add another dependency it overwrites my configuration. See the dependencies block in the code below.

Why is it not adding another dependency and is there a better way to do this?

app:build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    ivy {
        url property("artifactoryUrl")
        credentials {
            username property("artifactoryUser")
            password property("artifactoryPassword")
        }
        authentication {
            basic(BasicAuthentication)
        }
        patternLayout {
            artifact '/[organisation]/[module]/third-party/[revision](.[ext])'
        }
        metadataSources {
            artifact()
        }
    }
}

configurations {
    thirdPartyDependencies
}

dependencies {
    thirdPartyDependencies "artifactory:test-generic:FreeImage@zip"
    thirdPartyDependencies "artifactory:test-generic:GLEW@zip" // thirdPartyDependencies has been overwritten
}

task CopyThirdPartyDependencies(type: Copy) {

    def thirdPartyDirectory = getProject().getRootDir().toString() + "/third-party/"
    println(configurations.thirdPartyDependencies.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts)

    configurations.thirdPartyDependencies.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.each { artifact ->
        copy {
            from zipTree(artifact.getFile())
            into thirdPartyDirectory
        }
    }
}

preBuild.dependsOn(CopyThirdPartyDependencies)
```